# Java native error in Android

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface, native

I am getting erros in Java Native at runtime in com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFCore.getText2Internal(Native Method)
. Here is the log. I can't seem to identify the problem. I am trying to write a wrapper on top of Mupdf. If you need me show some code please let me know.

```
09-11 11:19:43.039: W/dalvikvm(3131): threadid=4: spin on suspend #1 threadid=10 (pcf=0)
09-11 11:19:43.789: W/dalvikvm(3131): threadid=4: spin on suspend #2 threadid=10 (pcf=3)
09-11 11:19:43.789: I/dalvikvm(3131): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
09-11 11:19:43.789: I/dalvikvm(3131):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40510b68 self=0x173a38
09-11 11:19:43.789: I/dalvikvm(3131):   | sysTid=3136 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1207328
09-11 11:19:43.789: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
09-11 11:19:43.789: I/dalvikvm(3131): "AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=10 RUNNABLE
09-11 11:19:43.789: I/dalvikvm(3131):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40511508 self=0x1d3338
09-11 11:19:43.789: I/dalvikvm(3131):   | sysTid=3207 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1913968
09-11 11:19:43.859: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFCore.getText2Internal(Native Method)
09-11 11:19:43.859: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFCore.getText2(MuPDFCore.java:155)
09-11 11:19:43.859: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFCore.gotoPage(MuPDFCore.java:77)
09-11 11:19:43.859: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFCore.getPageSize(MuPDFCore.java:84)
09-11 11:19:43.859: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFPageAdapter$1.doInBackground(MuPDFPageAdapter.java:54)
09-11 11:19:43.859: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFPageAdapter$1.doInBackground(MuPDFPageAdapter.java:1)
09-11 11:19:43.859: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-11 11:19:43.859: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
09-11 11:19:43.859: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
09-11 11:19:43.859: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
09-11 11:19:43.869: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
09-11 11:19:43.869: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
09-11 11:19:44.619: W/dalvikvm(3131): threadid=4: spin on suspend #3 threadid=10 (pcf=3)
09-11 11:19:44.619: I/dalvikvm(3131): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
09-11 11:19:44.619: I/dalvikvm(3131):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40510b68 self=0x173a38
09-11 11:19:44.619: I/dalvikvm(3131):   | sysTid=3136 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1207328
09-11 11:19:44.619: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
09-11 11:19:44.619: I/dalvikvm(3131): "AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=10 RUNNABLE
09-11 11:19:44.619: I/dalvikvm(3131):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40511508 self=0x1d3338
09-11 11:19:44.619: I/dalvikvm(3131):   | sysTid=3207 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1913968
09-11 11:19:46.549: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFCore.getText2Internal(Native Method)
09-11 11:19:46.549: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFCore.getText2(MuPDFCore.java:155)
09-11 11:19:46.549: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFCore.gotoPage(MuPDFCore.java:77)
09-11 11:19:46.549: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFCore.getPageSize(MuPDFCore.java:84)
09-11 11:19:46.549: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFPageAdapter$1.doInBackground(MuPDFPageAdapter.java:54)
09-11 11:19:46.549: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFPageAdapter$1.doInBackground(MuPDFPageAdapter.java:1)
09-11 11:19:46.549: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-11 11:19:46.549: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
09-11 11:19:46.549: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
09-11 11:19:46.549: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
09-11 11:19:46.549: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
09-11 11:19:46.549: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
09-11 11:19:47.299: W/dalvikvm(3131): threadid=4: spin on suspend #4 threadid=10 (pcf=3)
09-11 11:19:47.299: I/dalvikvm(3131): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
09-11 11:19:47.299: I/dalvikvm(3131):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40510b68 self=0x173a38
09-11 11:19:47.299: I/dalvikvm(3131):   | sysTid=3136 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1207328
09-11 11:19:47.299: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
09-11 11:19:47.299: I/dalvikvm(3131): "AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=10 RUNNABLE
09-11 11:19:47.299: I/dalvikvm(3131):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40511508 self=0x1d3338
09-11 11:19:47.299: I/dalvikvm(3131):   | sysTid=3207 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1913968
09-11 11:19:47.319: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFCore.getText2Internal(Native Method)
09-11 11:19:47.319: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFCore.getText2(MuPDFCore.java:155)
09-11 11:19:47.319: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFCore.gotoPage(MuPDFCore.java:77)
09-11 11:19:47.319: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFCore.getPageSize(MuPDFCore.java:84)
09-11 11:19:47.319: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFPageAdapter$1.doInBackground(MuPDFPageAdapter.java:54)
09-11 11:19:47.319: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFPageAdapter$1.doInBackground(MuPDFPageAdapter.java:1)
09-11 11:19:47.319: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-11 11:19:47.319: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
09-11 11:19:47.319: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
09-11 11:19:47.319: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
09-11 11:19:47.319: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
09-11 11:19:47.319: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
09-11 11:19:48.069: W/dalvikvm(3131): threadid=4: spin on suspend #5 threadid=10 (pcf=3)
09-11 11:19:48.069: I/dalvikvm(3131): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
09-11 11:19:48.069: I/dalvikvm(3131):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40510b68 self=0x173a38
09-11 11:19:48.069: I/dalvikvm(3131):   | sysTid=3136 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1207328
09-11 11:19:48.069: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
09-11 11:19:48.069: I/dalvikvm(3131): "AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=10 RUNNABLE
09-11 11:19:48.069: I/dalvikvm(3131):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40511508 self=0x1d3338
09-11 11:19:48.069: I/dalvikvm(3131):   | sysTid=3207 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1913968
09-11 11:19:48.069: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFCore.getText2Internal(Native Method)
09-11 11:19:48.069: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFCore.getText2(MuPDFCore.java:155)
09-11 11:19:48.069: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFCore.gotoPage(MuPDFCore.java:77)
09-11 11:19:48.069: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFCore.getPageSize(MuPDFCore.java:84)
09-11 11:19:48.069: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFPageAdapter$1.doInBackground(MuPDFPageAdapter.java:54)
09-11 11:19:48.069: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFPageAdapter$1.doInBackground(MuPDFPageAdapter.java:1)
09-11 11:19:48.069: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-11 11:19:48.069: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
09-11 11:19:48.069: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
09-11 11:19:48.069: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
09-11 11:19:48.069: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
09-11 11:19:48.069: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
09-11 11:19:48.819: W/dalvikvm(3131): threadid=4: spin on suspend #6 threadid=10 (pcf=3)
09-11 11:19:48.819: I/dalvikvm(3131): "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=4 RUNNABLE
09-11 11:19:48.819: I/dalvikvm(3131):   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x40510b68 self=0x173a38
09-11 11:19:48.819: I/dalvikvm(3131):   | sysTid=3136 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1207328
09-11 11:19:48.819: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
09-11 11:19:48.819: I/dalvikvm(3131): "AsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=10 RUNNABLE
09-11 11:19:48.819: I/dalvikvm(3131):   | group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x40511508 self=0x1d3338
09-11 11:19:48.819: I/dalvikvm(3131):   | sysTid=3207 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1913968
09-11 11:19:48.829: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFCore.getText2Internal(Native Method)
09-11 11:19:48.829: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFCore.getText2(MuPDFCore.java:155)
09-11 11:19:48.829: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFCore.gotoPage(MuPDFCore.java:77)
09-11 11:19:48.829: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFCore.getPageSize(MuPDFCore.java:84)
09-11 11:19:48.829: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFPageAdapter$1.doInBackground(MuPDFPageAdapter.java:54)
09-11 11:19:48.829: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at com.artifex.mupdf.MuPDFPageAdapter$1.doInBackground(MuPDFPageAdapter.java:1)
09-11 11:19:48.829: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-11 11:19:48.829: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
09-11 11:19:48.829: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
09-11 11:19:48.829: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
09-11 11:19:48.829: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
09-11 11:19:48.829: I/dalvikvm(3131):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: I got Eye damage from this exception :)

Comment: I found the reason for the crash, it was due to bad memory management. I was allocating a lot of memory and deallocating none. Workaround for this was to simply pass values in native types back to java using methods and not allocate any memory in JNI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for the crash, it was due to bad memory management. I was allocating a lot of memory and deallocating none. Workaround for this was to simply pass values in native types back to java using methods and not allocate any memory in JNI